# Python: Quit IDLE after Script running

Tags: python, exit, python-idle

Is it possible to somehow quit Python IDLE under Windows from within my python code/script at the end after running?

I tried something like:

```
import sys
sys.exit(0) # or exit(1)
```

didn't work. Probably only quits the current "process" of the running python script.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Why do you need to do this? (If I had this problem I would create a short AutoHotKey script using the [WinKill](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinKill.htm) command and then call that from my Python script.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can run IDLE from the command line (or edit your shortcut), I found this in the IDLE help.

```
If IDLE is started with the -n command line switch it will run in a
single process and will not create the subprocess which runs the RPC
Python execution server.
```

Which seems to imply that the script is running *inside* IDLE. I did a quick test script, and calling `exit()` brought up a box asking to kill the program. Clicked yes, and the script and IDLE both quit. Hope that can help.

Comment: Thanks that works, but IDLE prompts me before quitting. It would be nice to avoid that prompt - somehow possible!?

Answer (score 4):

This will do exactly what you want. No prompt.

```
import os
os.system("taskkill /f /im pythonw.exe")
```

Comment: Thank you, it works now, but it also kills all other python programs. Is it possible to kill only shell?

Answer (score 1):

To quit Python IDLE under Windows from within a python code/script without a further prompt, try:

```
parent_pid = os.getppid()  # Get parent's process id
parent_process = None
for proc in psutil.process_iter(attrs=['pid']):  # Check all processes
    if proc.pid == parent_pid:  # Parent's Process class
        parent_process = proc
        break

if parent_process is not None:
    parent_process.kill()  # Kill the parent's process
```

This works with IDLE, PyCharm and even the command line in Windows.